# Crash upon iPhone Simulator 5.0 startup

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I'm making an iPhone RPG application, I was working on programming a CGPoint array to some sprites I wanted to add, but I didn't make any progress and thus deleted the code.

After this, an exception was thrown each time I ran the app' on the iPhone Simulator, it said it was to do with OpenAL, so I took all of the sound code out.

The project then ran fine on the iPhone Simulator, without sound though of course.

Now, upon taking all of my newly added code out, the iPhone Simulator crashes (freezes) when it's still on the Cocos2d load up screen and points to the following line of code in Xcode:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

I've been looking over my code with a fine-tooth comb for an hour now, checking in case I left any code in or changed anything, and I haven't.

Has anyone had any experience with this problem? Or can anyone give me an idea what might have happened?

Some light to shine on the OpenAL problem would be nice too (second time it's happened to me).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in situations such as these is put break points all over the place and look for the point at which the applications crashes from.

If you haven't yet check out the stack for any clues. Unfortunately if there is nothing on the stack or printed from the debugger this is really all you can do.

Comment: This occured after I tried to run my project on my iPhone - it failed and I decided to scrap it. Following this, I was getting said error. The debugged says "Couldn't register com.yourcompany.Gamev2 with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger." This project is due in in 3 weeks, and I can't believe I've came across this now! Objective C has proved to be a rather annoying head-ache! Dunno if it's just me...

Answer (score 0):

So I checked some other questions AGAIN, and found someone saying to restart the computer... This worked. It's annoying, so so annoying. But that's what worked.

Also, for any weird errors, just make sure you Product > Clean after adding/changing any resources you use.